# I can't get the printf result if the third conditional is true

Tags: c, if-statement

I know I can write this code with fewer lines and I did it before, but I tried with an "if else" chain to explore different ways to code the same program since I'm still learning the basics. But doing this way I can't get the result if the third conditional(C is the greater one) is true. Only if the third conditional is true the program finish without printing anything. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){
    int a, b, c = 0;

    printf("Please insert three different numbers:\n");
    printf("Insert A value:");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Insert B value:");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("Insert C value:");
    scanf("%d", &c);

    //comparing A, B and C to find the greater number
    if(a > b){
        if (a > c){
            printf("\nThe greater is A: %d", a);
        }
    }else if (b > a){
        if(b > c){
            printf("\nThe greater is B: %d", b);
        }
    }else{
        printf("\nThe greater is C: %d", c);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your final else will be entered only when a==b. It doesn't, however, reqire that c > a

Comment: What values do you enter?  You should check `if (a == b || a == c || b == c) printf("The numbers a = %d, b = %d, c = %d are not all different\n"; else …` — people are very bad at following instructions and routinely enter data wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you `if` statements to this:

```
        if(a > b && a > c){
                printf("\nThe greater is A: %d", a);
        }else if (b > a && b > c){
                printf("\nThe greater is B: %d", b);  
        }else if (c > a && c > b){
            printf("\nThe greater is C: %d", c);
        }
```

Also, using the same structure you have, you can use this:

```
    if(a > b){
        if (a > c){
            printf("\nThe greater is A: %d", a);
        }else {
            printf("\nThe greater is C: %d", c);
        }
    }else if (b > a){
        if(b > c){
            printf("\nThe greater is B: %d", b);
        }else{
            printf("\nThe greater is C: %d", c);
        }
```